# Location to save initial data file?

Tags: ios, swift, nsbundle

Warning, I'm a designer, stumbling my way around Swift, so apologies ahead of time for my ignorance.

The app I'm working on will ship with a JSON data file with all data (so that the app is accessible without connection).  When the app runs I check a remote JSON file to see if there have been any updates to the data.  If there is new data then I'll overwrite the local file with the newer JSON file.

My question isn't directly related to code, but the iOS file system.  I know that I can't write to the main bundle, so where do I put the starting JSON file so that I can access it from the Documents directory?
I understand how to save new files to Documents with code and all that, but I don't know how to put the JSON file into the Documents directory to start with.

Just a point in the right direction would be great.

Thanks

Comment: You mean you have one JSON file into bundle and you want to put it into document directory?

Comment: Yes essentially.  From what I've gathered the file needs to be in a writeable location and not in the main bundle, which I'm assume is the core app directory.  Maybe I'm taking this totally wrong, I don't have much to go on, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be helpful to you. By using this you can create files in the application data or fetch files from application data.

```
   var paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as! String
   var dirPath = paths.stringByAppendingPathComponent("XYZ/")

   var docPath = paths.stringByAppendingPathComponent("XYZ/xyz.json" )
   println(docPath)
   var checkImage = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

   if (checkImage.fileExistsAtPath(docPath)) {


    } else
    {
         checkImage.createDirectoryAtPath(dirPath, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil, error: nil)

    }
```

For deleting specific use this

```
   checkImage.removeItemAtPath(imagePath, error: nil)
```

Answer (score 2):

You put the initial file into your bundle and leave it there forever. If you download a newer file, since that file could be downloaded again if needed, the OS should be able to delete it at any time, and the file should not be backed up. Therefore, you put it into your cache directory. Apple's reviewer don't like it if you immediately copy the file.

When the app starts, you check whether you have a file in the cache directory. If it's there, you use it and check its version number. If it's not there, you take the file from the bundle. In either case, you check if there is a newer version available in the background.

The one thing you *don't* do is make a copy of the file in your bundle.

Comment: I think my issue was that I was looking to put the document into the 'Documents' directory from within Xcode.  So what I need to do is just leave it in the main directory and then save future files into the Documents directory?